# The Network Adapter could not establish the connection org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, exception, jdbc

The Hibernate Program runs for some transactions and after that it cannot establish connections. The Exception is as following:

```
WARN: SQL Error: 17002, SQLState: null
Feb 01, 2012 11:47:10 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
Feb 01, 2012 11:52:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading this Context has started
```

Comment: What is your jdbc URL ?
You should check it's correct: port number, ...

Comment: can you telnet on the database and its port ?

Answer (score 0):

Check your class path setting: It should contain the location of `oracle-jdbc6.jar`.

Comment: That would not cause this problem. This  message is printed by a class in that JAR file. -1